# Disable 'Delete' icon in ribbon when viewing/editing a list item (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath 2010 form which prevents users from modifying items if they are not in the list of 'Editors' - by showing a read only form based on rules run by the form. However, the 'Delete' icon is still visible when viewing an item, how can I remove it (or at least only show to site owners).

I am aware that you can restrict it so that the user can edit their own items, but I want to be able to allow users to set who else is able to edit a list item.

Comment: What do you call 'item'? a row in a repeating section/table control of the form? or the actual form in the form library?

Comment: An 'item' is this case is a 'list item', an entry added to a list

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom Permission Level with Delete permission removed and item-level or folder-level permissions, but this can cause you a lot of headache managing the broken inheritance of permissions.